# Should I accept empty collections in my methods that iterate over them?

Tags: c#, exceptions, collections, parameters

I have a method where all logic is performed inside a foreach loop that iterates over the method's parameter:

```
public IEnumerable<TransformedNode> TransformNodes(IEnumerable<Node> nodes)
{
    foreach(var node in nodes)
    {
        // yadda yadda yadda
        yield return transformedNode;
    }
}
```

In this case, sending in an empty collection results in an empty collection, but I'm wondering if that's unwise.

My logic here is that if somebody is calling this method, then they intend to pass data in, and would only pass an empty collection to my method in erroneous circumstances.

Should I catch this behaviour and throw an exception for it, or is it best practice to return the empty collection?

Comment: Are you sure your assumption "if somebody is calling this method, then they intend to pass data in" is correct? Maybe they are just passing what they got at hand to work with the result.

Comment: True, I guess I figured they should check what data they were holding first, but the answers so far are convincing that if there's nothing wrong with an empty collection don't throw an exception for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expected behavior when an request for a collection will have zero items](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/161149/expected-behavior-when-an-request-for-a-collection-will-have-zero-items)

Comment: @gnat that's for whether something should return an empty collection. In this case, I'm asking about the specific case of when an empty collection is passed in. While this returns an empty collection, sure, the question more specifically addresses *input etiquette* as opposed to your linked question's *output etiquette*.

Comment: I see, this is related but not a duplicate indeed (retracted my vote)

Comment: BTW: your "transform" method is usually called "map", although in .NET (and SQL, which is where .NET got the name from), it is commonly called "select". "Transform" is what C++ calls it, but that is not a common name that one might recognize.

Comment: I'd throw if the collection is `null` but not if it's empty.

Comment: If you can imagine a user wanting to be informed when she's passed you an empty collection you can write a wrapper for this that checks. Then your client can decide whether to call the wrapper, or your method directly.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes.  And it may well be better to return null, if no other meaningful answer can be given, than throw an exception (showing my FP bias).  I would say that is a cleaner option than Ethan Bolker´s wrapper.

Comment: What is the harm if the collection is empty?

Comment: @rmayer06 There's no harm explicitly, but it is pointless to call such a method on an empty collection, so I wondered if it would be best at that point to inform the caller via an exception. The answers have persuaded me to not do so.

Comment: @NickUdell - I pass empty collections around in my code all the time. It's easier for code to behave the same than write special branching logic for cases where I could not add anything to my collection before moving on with it.

Comment: If you check and throw an error if the collection is empty, then you are forcing your caller to also check and not pass an empty collection to your method. Validations should be done on (and only on) system boundaries, if empty collections bothers you, you should have already checked them on long before it reached any utility methods. Now you have two redundant checks.

Comment: If you had a function taking an integer would you ask "should I accept 0 as input in my methods?" Because the empty collection is a *completely valid* collection as `0` is for numbers. It's just a "degenerate case" but not an invalid one, and degenerate cases *do* have valid answers.

Comment: Rather than use yield returns, it might be preferable to extract a method for converting a single `Node` to a `TransformedNode` and replace your utility method with LINQ `collection.Select(TransformNode)` calls.

Comment: @LieRyan surely having two redundant checks is a good thing? This one guards against programmer error higher up the call graph. It seems odd to prescribe against a useful check here, because there should be another useful check somewhere out of scope. This check is basically a check for that check.

Comment: Every redundant checks means extra code to maintain, which means more places for bugs; a possible exception also need to be documented, which makes the method's interface harder to understand; also adding business layer checks into utilities reduces its composibility/reusability. Checks are useful sure, but it must be weighed against its downsides. If your system is so large that an extra check around this area would actually be useful, you probably want to partition them into subsystems with well-defined boundaries and make all the checks you need when crossing between the subsystems.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Utility methods should not throw on empty collections. Your API clients would hate you for it.

A collection can be empty; a "collection-that-must-not-be-empty" is conceptually a much more difficult thing to work with.

Transforming an empty collection has an obvious outcome: the empty collection. (You may even save some garbage by returning the parameter itself.)

There are many circumstances in which a module maintains lists of stuff that may or may not be already filled with something. Having to check for emptiness before each and every call to `transform` is annoying and has the potential to turn a simple, elegant algorithm into an ugly mess.

Utility methods should always strive to be liberal in their inputs and conservative in their outputs.

For all these reasons, for God's sake, handle the empty collection correctly. Nothing is more exasperating than a helper module that *thinks* it knows what you want better than you do.

Comment: +1 - (more if I could). I might even go so far as to also coalesce `null` into the empty collection. Functions with implicit limitations are a pain.

Comment: "No you shouldn't"... shouldn't accept them or shouldn't throw an exception?

Comment: I don't think this should be the accepted answer.  Its a blanket statement, and there very well may be situations were not having any data to process is an error and not throwing hides this error, just like returning an empty collection when the enumerable passed was null might hide errors as well.

Comment: @BenAaronson Agreed, it's not very clear what you're actually suggesting here specifically with regards to OP's question.

Comment: @Andy - those wouldn't be **utility** methods though. They'd be business methods or some similar concrete behavior.

Comment: I don't think recycling the empty collection for a return is a good idea.  You're only saving a tiny bit of memory; and it could result in unexpected behavior in the caller. Slightly contrived example: `Populate1(input);  output1 = TransformNodes(input); Populate2(input); output2 = TransformNodes(input);`  If Populate1 left the collection empty and you returned it for the first TransformNodes call, output1 and input would be the same collection, and when Populaten2 was called if it did put nodes in the collection you'd end up with your second set of input in output2.

Comment: @Telastyn Sorry, but where did the OP say he was writing a general utility method?

Comment: @andy - the answer made that qualification, making it not so blanket a statement.

Comment: @Telastyn Yes, and that's the only type of method the answer covers; it doesn't discuss at all any other option.

Comment: Such a function named what it is would violate all sorts of principles of abstraction if we also expect it to throw all kinds of exceptions. The point is that an exception is not necessary until it is.

Comment: @Andy Even so, if the argument should never be empty - if it is an error to have no data to process - then I feel it's the responsibility of the **caller** to check this, when it's collating that argument.  Not only does it keep this method more elegant, but it means one can generate a better error message (better context) and raise it in a fail-fast way.  It doesn't make sense for a downstream class to verify the caller's invariants...

Comment: @Andy If it is needed to be made sure, you just can hafe a filter function which returns its parameter when not empty, but throws on empty. It then can be used separately from the one discussed here.

Comment: +1.  @Andy, glglgl's point shows why accepting the empty set and allowing the caller to choose aids function composition.  An exception in this case greatly restricts the composability and flexibility of the function.

Comment: Please pay attention to @DanNeely's comment. For `$DEITY`'s sake.

Comment: @itsbruce You seem to think I dont understand that point, I do.  But there are cases where the compositbility is less important than having no data, which is why I'm saying "it depends"

Comment: @Telastyn: Don't conflate `null` and default (whatever that might mean for the type). You might want to pass the `null` on, but I far prefer an error at the earliest possible place to *naturally* trip over my logic-error, so debugging is easier. Also, default and `null` are often both useful and two very significantly different states.

Comment: @Deduplicator - I'm not saying everywhere, but if you pass me an enumerable that is null, interpreting that as an empty collection is very often better than being fragile.

Comment: I have to throw a -1 for "You may even save some garbage by returning the parameter itself.", see above comments.

Comment: @Andy why on earth should we use drastically different patterns for "utility" methods versus other methods? Put another way, if adequate decomposition of the problem space was performed prior to code construction, how many methods are there *really* that aren't "utility" methods? I vote for using the same *patterns* in as many places as possible, which tends to make exceptions to the patterns stand out and makes the whole easier to comprehend. The fewer methods exist that are individualized "works of art," the better.

Comment: @Craig I really dont get what people are missing here; all I said was this as a hard and fast rule isn't good, and there are cases were it might be appropriate to throw instead of return normally.  I dont even get why the answerer threw in utility method and then when on from there.  As far as pushing for patterns for the sake of it, that is a terrible idea, its actually an antipattern.  Patterns should be used when they fit, and you should not force a pattern onto a problem that doesn't quite fit.  In other words, this job requires THINKING.

Comment: +1 for the general spirit of the answer, -1 for suggesting an "optimization" that creates an alias when given an empty collection, when the return value is a new object in every other case.

Comment: @Telastyn: I would be *far* more comfortable if you were suggesting the function return `null` when given `null`, rather than silently converting `null` input into an empty collection.

Comment: @Andy, of course the job requires thinking. I totally disagree that attempting to use common patterns "for the sake of it" is an anti-pattern, though. I'm not talking about formal "gang of 4" patterns. I'm talking about common ways of doing similar (or identical) things, leading to predictable results, which leads to lower bug counts and easier comprehension when bugs inevitably pop up and have to be investigated and fixed. I'm talking about **conventions** to a large degree, and there are plenty of conventions-based frameworks popping up that support that general approach.

Comment: Treating each and every new function as if it's something totally unique and new to the world is an anti-pattern. That's all I'm really saying. Part of the thinking you're referring to ought to include putting in the effort to consider how "this" problem is very similar (or identical) to other problems that are already solved, whether by me, by somebody else who I can pattern my code after, or by general consensus. I'll defend what I said before; use of patterns (**conventions**) to the greatest degree possible leads to more rapid, more accurate comprehension, thus more reliable code.

Comment: @Hurkyl, my only contention would be that if the method can return null when the caller is justifiably expecting a collection, then you are in effect returning two different data types and forcing the caller to work harder. They must check for null before they can even check to see if the set is empty, if they care whether the set is empty. If they can just presume that the function returns a collection, they can simply iterate that collection and design their code to come off with the right behavior if the set is empty. If they can't presume that, I'd *almost* rather see an exception thrown.

Comment: ...and that exception would be an ArgumentException, right? Because what you're really saying in that case is that the incoming null is invalid because it prevents you from returning a collection.

Comment: ...well, a NullArgumentException, indicating explicitly that the parameter is rejected because it is null. Quietly accepting the null and returning a null is probably a bug, because it just masks what is actually an error, which means there is going to be a side-effect somewhere else, and even worse you're going to ship that bug and only find out about it when it corrupts your customers' data.

Comment: @Craig: I argue that one justifiably should *not* be expecting a collection if they pass `null` into a "transform-outputs-of-an-iterable" function, except in the particular context of a project that has adopted both the *convention* that `null` means `empty collection` and that functions should normalize `null` to `empty collection` upon return. Outside of such a context, silently converting `null` into an empty collection is far more likely to result in a bug. Returning `null`, at least, preserves the superficial semantics: transforming 'not a collection' results in 'not a collection'.

Comment: @Hurkyl I still think it's probably better to throw a `NullArgumentException` than to just return `null`. That's what I was really getting at. Chances are pretty good that the caller is passing a value it obtained from somewhere else. Agreed that returning an empty set may violate the conventions of the project, in which case throwing `NullArgumentException` would probably lead to earlier discovery of the underlying bug (probably a bogus assumption further up the call stack), leading a fix earlier in the development cycle. At the very least there should probably be an `Assert`, no?  ;-)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19048/discussion-on-answer-by-kilian-foth-should-i-accept-empty-collections-in-my-meth).

Answer (score 26):

I see two important questions which determine the answer to this:

1. Can your function return anything meaningful and logical when passed an empty collection (including **null**)?
2. What is the general programming style in this applicaton/library/team?  (Specifically, how FP are you?)

**1. Meaningful return**

Essentially, if you can return something meaningful, then do not throw an exception.  Let the caller deal with the result.  So if your function...

- Counts the number of elements in the collection, return 0.  That was easy.
- Searches for elements which match particular criteria, return an empty collection.  Please do not throw anything.  The caller may have a huge collection of collections, some of which are empty, some not.  The caller wants any matching elements in any collection.  Exceptions only make the caller´s life harder.
- Is looking for the largest/smallest/best-fit-to-the-criteria in the list.  Oops.  Depending on the style question, you might throw an exception here or you could return **null**.  I hate null (very much an FP person) but it is arguably more meaningful here and it lets you reserve exceptions for unexpected errors within your own code.  If the caller doesn´t check for null, a fairly clear exception will result anyway.  But you leave that to them.
- Asks for the nth item in the collection or the first/last n items.  This is the best case for an exception yet and the one that is least likely to cause confusion and difficulty for the caller.  A case can still be made for **null** if you and your team are used to checking for that, for all the reasons given in the previous point, but this is the most valid case yet for throwing a **DudeYou*Know*YouShouldCheckTheSizeFirst** exception.  If your style is more functional, then either **null** or read on to my **Style** answer.

In general, my FP bias tells me ¨return something meaningful¨ and **null** can have valid meaning in this case.

**2.  Style**

Does your general code (or the project´s code or the team´s code) favour a functional style?  If no, exceptions will be expected and dealt with.  If yes, then consider returning an [Option Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type).  With an option type, you either return a meaningful answer or **None/Nothing**.  In my third example from above, **Nothing** would be a good answer in FP style.  The fact that the function returns an Option type signals clearly to the caller than a meaningful answer may not be possible and that the caller should be prepared to deal with that.  I feel it gives the caller more options (if you will forgive the pun).

F# is where all the cool .Net kids do this kind of thing but C# *does* [support](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/375166/Functional-programming-in-Csharp) this style.

**tl;dr**

Keep exceptions for unexpected errors in your own code path,  not entirely foreseeable (and legal) input from somebody else´s.

Comment: "Best fit" etc.: You may have a method that finds the best fit object in a collection that matches some criterion. That method would have the same problem for non-empty collections, because nothing might fit the criterion, so no need to worry about empty selections.

Comment: No, that is why I said ¨best fit¨ and not ¨matches¨; the phrase implies the closest approximation, not an exact match.  The largest/smallest options should have been a clue.  If only ¨best fit¨ has been asked for, then any collection with 1 or more members should be able to return a member.  If there is only one member, that is the best fit.

Comment: Return "null" in most cases is worse then throwing a exception.   However returning an empty collection is meaningful.

Comment: Not if you have to return a single item (min/max/head/tail).  As for null, as I said, I hate it (and prefer languages which do not have it), but where a language does have it, you have to be able to deal with it and code that hands it out.  Depending on the local coding conventions, it may be appropriate.

Comment: None of your examples have anything to do with an empty input. They're just *special cases* of situations where the answer might be "nothing." Which in turn should answer the OP's question about how to "handle" the empty collection.

Comment: @AAA Each of my examples discusses what to do if an empty collection is passed as input.  Your logic - or reading comprehension - seems a little faulty.  What did you *think* I was envisaging as input when I recommended returning 0 for the collection size?  Did you think I started with *"Can your function return anything meaningful and logical when passed an empty collection?"* as a distraction?  I offer 4 different types of answers, so it seems bizarre to say that my examples are linked by the return value rather than the input.

Answer (score 18):

As ever, it depends.

Does it *matter* that the collection is empty?
Most collection-handling code would probably say "no"; a collection can have *any number* of items in it, *including* zero.

Now, if you have some sort of collection where it is "invalid" to have no items in it, then that's a new requirement and you have to decide what to do about it.

Borrow some testing logic from the Database world: test for *zero* items, *one* item and *two* items.  That caters for the most important cases (flushing out any badly-formed inner or cartesian join conditions).

Comment: And if it's invalid to have no items in a collection, then ideally the argument wouldn't be a `java.util.Collection`, but a custom `com.foo.util.NonEmptyCollection` class, that can consistently preserve this invariant, and prevent you from getting into an invalid state to start with.

Comment: This question is tagged [c#]

Comment: @NickUdell does C# not support Object Oriented programming or the concept of nested namespaces? TIL.

Comment: It does. My comment was a clarification as Andrzej must have been confused (for why else would they go to the effort of specifying namespaced for a language this question does not reference?).

Comment: -1 for emphasizing the "it depends" more than the "almost certainly yes". No joke - communicating the wrong thing does damage here.

Answer (score 11):

As a matter of good design, accept as much variation in your inputs as practical or possible. Exceptions should *only* be thrown when (unacceptable input is presented OR unexpected errors happen while processing) **AND the program cannot continue in a predictable way** as a result.

In this case, it should be expected that an empty collection will be presented, and your code needs to handle it (which it already does). It would be a violation of all that is good if your code threw an exception here.  This would be akin to multiplying 0 by 0 in mathematics. It is redundant, but absolutely necessary for it to work the way it does.

Now, on to the null collection argument. In this case, a null collection is a programming mistake: the programmer forgot to assign a variable. This is a case where an exception could be thrown, because you cannot meaningfully process that into an output, and attempting to do so would introduce unexpected behavior.  This would be akin to dividing by zero in mathematics - it is completely meaningless.

Comment: Your bold statement is extremely bad advice in full generality. I think it's true here but you need to explain what's special about this circumstance. (It's bad advice in general because it promotes silent failures.)

Comment: @AAA - clearly we're not writing a book on how to design software here, but I don't think it's bad advice at all if you really understand what I am saying. My point is that were bad input produces ambiguous or arbitrary output, you need to throw an exception. In cases where the output is totally predictable (as is the case here), then throwing an exception would be arbitrary. The key is never to make arbitrary decisions in your program, as that is where unpredictable behavior comes from.

Comment: But it's your first sentence and the only highlighted one... no one understands what you are saying yet. (I'm not trying to be too aggressive here, just one of the things we're here to do is learn to write and communicate and I do thing the loss of precision in a key point is harmful.)

Answer (score 10):

The right solution is much harder to see when you are just looking at your function in isolation.  Consider your function as one part of [a larger problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169870/1069).  One possible solution to that example looks like this (in Scala):

```scala
input.split("\\D")
.filterNot (_.isEmpty)
.map (_.toInt)
.filter (x => x >= 1000 && x <= 9999)
```

First, you split the string up by non-digits, filter out the empty strings, convert the strings to integers, then filter to keep only the four-digit numbers.  Your function might be the `map (_.toInt)` in the pipeline.

This code is fairly straightforward because each stage in the pipeline just handles an empty string or an empty collection.  If you put an empty string in at the start, you get an empty list out at the end.  You don't have to stop and check for `null` or an exception after every call.

Of course, that's presuming an empty output list doesn't have more than one meaning.  If you *need* to differentiate between an empty output caused by empty input and one caused by the transform itself, that completely changes things.

Comment: +1 for extremely effective example (lacking in the other good answers).

Answer (score 2):

This question is actually about exceptions. If you look at it that way and ignore the empty collection as an implementation detail, the answer is straightforward:

1) A method should throw an exception when it can't proceed: either unable to do the designated task, or return the appropriaate value.

2) A method should catch an exception when it is able to proceed despite the failure.

So, your helper method should not be "helpful" and throw an exception unless **it** is unable to do it's job with an empty collection.  Let the caller determine whether the results can be handled.

Whether it returns an empty collection or null, is a bit more difficult but not much: nullable collections should be avoided if possible.   The purpose of a nullable collection would be to indicate (as in SQL) that you don't have the information -- a collection of children for example might be null if you don't know if someone has any, but you don't know that they don't.  But if that is important for some reason, it's probably worth an extra variable to track it.

Answer (score 1):

The method is named `TransformNodes`. In case of an empty collection as input,
getting back an empty collection is natural and intuitive,
and makes prefect mathematical sense.

If the method was named `Max` and designed to return the maximum element, then it would be natural to throw `NoSuchElementException` on an empty collection, as the maximum of nothing makes no mathematical sense.

If the method was named `JoinSqlColumnNames` and designed to return a string where the elements are joined by a comma to use in SQL queries, then it would make sense to throw `IllegalArgumentException` on an empty collection, as the caller would eventually get an SQL error anyway if he used the string in an SQL query directly without further checks, and instead of checking for a returned empty string he really should have checked for empty collection instead.

Comment: `Max` of nothing is often negative infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Let's step back and use a different example which computes the arithmetic mean of an array of values.

If the input array is empty (or null), can you reasonably fulfill the caller's request? No. What are your options? Well, you could:

- present/return/throw an error. using your codebase's convention for that class of error.
- document that a value such as zero will be returned
- document that a designated invalid value will be returned (e.g. NaN)
- document that a magic value will be returned (e.g. a min or max for the type or some hopefully-indicative value)
- declare the result is unspecified
- declare the action is undefined
- etc.

I say give them the error if they have given you invalid input and the request cannot be completed. I mean a hard error from day one so they understand your program's requirements. After all, your function is not in a position to respond. If the operation *could* fail (e.g. copy a file), then your API should give them an error they can deal with.

So that can define how your library handles malformed requests and requests which may fail.

It's very important for your code to be consistent in how it handles these classes of errors.

The next category is to decide how your library handles nonsense requests. Getting back to an example similar to yours -- let's use a function which determines whether a file exists at a path: `bool FileExistsAtPath(String)`. If the client passes an empty string, how do you handle this scenario? How about an empty or null array passed to `void SaveDocuments(Array<Document>)`? Decide for your library/codebase, and *be consistent*. I happen to consider these cases errors, and forbid clients from making nonsense requests by flagging them as errors (via an assertion). Some people will strongly resist that idea/action. I find this error detection very helpful. It is very good for locating issues in programs -- with good locality to the offending program. Programs are much clearer and correct (consider evolution of your codebase), and don't burn cycles within functions which do nothing. Code's smaller/cleaner this way, and the checks are generally pushed out to the locations where the issue may be introduced.

Comment: For your last example, it's not that function's job to determine what is nonsense. Therefore, an empty string should return false.  Indeed, that is The exact approach [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes.

Comment: @rmayer06 it is its job. the referenced function permits null, empty strings, checks for invalid characters in the string, performs string truncation, may need to make filesystem calls, may need to query the environment, etc. those often-redundant-in-execution 'conveniences' have a high cost, and they definitely blur the lines of correctness (IMO). i've seen plenty of `if (!FileExists(path)) { ...create it!!!... }` bugs -- many of which would be caught before commit, were the lines of correctness not blurred.

Comment: I would I agree with you, if the name of the function was File.ThrowExceptionIfPathIsInvalid, but who in their right mind would call such function?

Comment: An average of 0 items is already going to either return NaN or throw a divide-by-zero exception, just because of how the function is defined.  A file with a name that can't possibly exist, either won't exist or will already trigger an error.  There's no compelling reason to handle these cases specially.

Comment: One could even argue that the whole concept of checking for a file's existence before reading or writing it, is flawed anyway.  (There's an inherent race condition.)  Better to just go ahead and try to open the file, for reading, or with create-only settings if you'for writing.  It'll already fail if the filename is invalid or doesn't exist (or does, in the case of writing).

Comment: One may reasonably check for a file's existence before starting some expensive operation which would be guaranteed to fail if the file's status isn't as expected, even if the file's status could never guarantee success.  Arguably, the real problem with methods like `FileExistsAtPath` is that can only answer one question, different routines which might use such a method actually want the answers to *different questions*, and the name doesn't make clear what exact question is supposedly being answered.

Comment: @cHao: See above comment. With regard to the broader question of whether a method that performs some operation on a collection should throw an exception on an empty collection, I would suggest that it depends whether the question the method is supposed to answer is well-defined for such collections. The total value of things in an empty collection is well-defined (zero), but the maximum, minimum, and average are not.  NaN might be reasonable, but could in some cases cause be no more helpful than a thrown exception.

Comment: @supercat: If no answer would make sense, then an exception could be reasonable.  If an exception would already be thrown, though, it's usually better IMO to just let it be thrown than to preemptively fail.  For the file case, you could open the file before starting processing.  You'll not only know the file exists, but in Windows, having the file open can keep other processes from messing with it, thereby avoiding the race condition altogether.

Comment: @cHao: If a potential problem condition would "naturally" cause a method to fail *before doing anything of significance* then letting the exception happen may be fine.  There are a fair number of situations, however, where ignoring problems early on will cause methods to "fail late" and potentially create additional problems.

Answer (score -3):

As a rule of thumb, a standard function should be able to accept the broadest list of inputs and give feedback on it, there are many examples where programmers use functions in ways that the designer had not planned, with this in mind i believe the function should be able to accept not only empty collections but a wide range of input types and gracefully return feedback, be it even an error object from whatever operation was performed on the input...

Comment: It is absolutely wrong for the designer to assume that a collection will always be passed and go straight to iterating over the said collection, a check must be done to ensure that the received argument conforms to the expected datatype...

Comment: "wide range of input types" looks irrelevant here. Question is tagged [tag:c#], a strongly typed language. That is, compiler guarantees that input is a collection

Comment: Kindly google "rule of thumb", my answer was a generalized caution that as a programmer you make room for unforeseen or erroneous occurrences, one of these can be erroneously passed function arguments...

Comment: This is either wrong or tautological. `writePaycheckToEmployee` should not accept a negative number as input... but if "feedback" means "does anything that might happen next," then yes every function will do something it does next.